# Want to now to send Cortana Email Mark-up for users to track?

Tags: windows-10, email, cortana

I am working on Cortana Email Markup, and as per my research and understanding https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632191.aspx I have found some schema that work for tracking flight reservation. But I want to know

1) Does Cortana track Gmail or only outlook mails?
2) Does it also track Packages,Events then will i get procedure and schema related     to it?